# Complex Regex that can filter word

Tags: regex, python-3.x, matching

Can someone help me with correct regex to match line1 and not line2. I want the match criteria to be based on

1. if the line starts with 'username' followed by 1 or more spaces
2. followed by a number and one or more spaces
3. followed by any string not containing 'grep' and ending with 'some/path/somescript.py'

The example below should, match line1 and not line2

```
line1 = "username   842 93.0  0.1 180740 36016 ?        Sl   Jan21 747:36 /some/path/somescript.py"
line2 = "username  8227  0.0  0.0  14356  2496 pts/5    S+   11:33   0:00 grep /some/path/somescript.py"
```

I tried `(^username\s*)(\d+\s*)` which meets Nos. 1 & 2 but am not sure how to meet the 3rd requirement. This [online](https://pythex.org/) tool might be helpful for test

Comment: If you are also having trouble with your Python code, you should post that in your question as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
^username\s+\d+\s+(?!.*grep).*some\/path\/somescript\.py$
```

### Demo

There is not much to explain here, except for this:

```
(?!.*grep)
```

This is a negative lookahead *assertion*, which says that at this exact spot in the pattern, to assert that we do not find `grep` anywhere in the remainder of the string.  That assertion having been found true, we then match:

```
.*some\/path\/somescript\.py$
```

That is, we match anything so long as the line ends in `some/path/somescript.py`.

Comment: Technically that final `.` should be escaped (`\.`).

Comment: @TomLord You're right...I'm setting up a demo now...ironically I would have gotten away with it...sort of.

Comment: Thank @TimBiegeleisen, please is there a way I can group this? such that it can be the matched result can be returned as array/list

Comment: @Paullo My Python 3 is almost non existent unfortunately.  I answered assuming you mainly were having trouble with the pattern.  Someone else can help you with the Python side of the question.

Comment: Thanks I got it (^username\s+)(\d+\s+)((?!.*grep).*\/some\/path\/somescript\.py$)